# Posgres Not storing images

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytJLI.png)Anybody know what may be causing this? I am building a Flask app and deployed on Heroku. I then uploaded posts to test the blog app and everything seemed to be fine but after some time the images were all gone. So, I am guessing my images are not being stored in my database?

This is my post upload Python Code:

```
@views.route('/addpost', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def addpost():
    if request.method =="POST":
        title = request.form.get('title')
        body = request.form.get('content')
        photo = save_images(request.files.get('photo'))
        post= Post(title=title, body=body, image=photo, author =current_user)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your post has been submitted", 'success')
        return redirect('dashboard')
    return render_template ('admin/addpost.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

All heroku dynos are restarted every 24 hours in a process called cycling. Any changes to the local filesystem will be deleted, so your images are not being stored locally. You can read more about this on [heroku's devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)